# Não está encontrando a pagina index

Tags: spring-boot

**PROBLEMA**

Quando executa o projeto não está encontrando a view index.jsp. Estou utilizando RESTFUL e WEB no spring boot.

**ERRO**

```
o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp]
```

**appplication.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.servlet.contextPath=/erp-rs
```

**IndexController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando o Tomcat com JSP terá que colocar essa dependência no pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Tudo ok.